# Dynamic Inheritance using a factory

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance, factory-pattern

I think I know the answer to this, but I'm hoping someone has a neat solution. We are currently using two kinds of drop down controls (Telerik and .Net). I'm hoping to combine these into one control, but struggling with a user friendly design.

Ideally, the control would be created in the design file with a bool property of, say, "SimpleBox," to determine which kind of control to inherit. The instantiation would then be generated in the code-behind design file and the constructor would then dynamically load the base (which isn't possible). The easy solution would be for me to create an IDropDown interface, then have a factory create the correct one. The only real problem with this is the fact that the instantiation has to be manually written every time, which is a hassle, and does not speed up our process at all.

Although it isn't directly possible, I'm looking for a solution along the lines of a factory which is run inside the object constructor for setting the base, based on a bool property.

Cheers

Comment: Why are you doing this?  Why is having a "SimpleBox" property better than simply choosing the correct control for the given situation and using it?

Comment: We have been using the telerik controls for everything, but since we are using so many on some of our pages telerik is generating many MB of code per page. Using the standard .net DropDownBox dramatically reduces size/speed. I'm planning to make an adapter for the DropDownBox so it can be plugged in place of the telerik combo. Of course I'm doing all this to limit refactoring (since have have coded thousands telerik combos) and to have common methods for all our dropdowns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to look into composition/delegation instead of inheritance here.

In essence, rather than extending either class directly, create a wrapper class that extends `Control` (or something similarly low-level) and implements `IDropDown`, add an `IDropDown` field for the underlying control implementation you want to use, and forward every method call of interest to the selected implementation.  This rapidly becomes tedious if there are a lot of methods, though.

Comment: I thought about this, but to further complicate the problem we currently have controls inheriting from our current base DropDownBox (which will be replaced with the hybrid). The inheriting controls are using protected event handlers, but since you can't have protected members in an interface i was getting all sorts of access issues, perhaps i was doing it wrong.

Comment: @`g.foley` - As you say, the interface can't have protected methods, but you have to have a base class that implements the interface, and the base class can have protected methods. The `IDropDown` interface can have event which allows your hybrid class to expose the events as needed.